# Restarting sidekiq periodically with a cronjob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

We are currently using `capistrano-sidekiq`, this also handles the automatic restart of sidekiq on each deploy.

However, we also want to manually restart sidekiq each night, without rebooting the whole application.

Which command should be used to automatically restart sidekiq on the production machine using a crontab entry on this machine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find existing sidekiq process and kill it and then start sidekiq again

## To run Sidekiq

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

## To Kill sidekiq process

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiqctl stop tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I stumbled across the following issue which describes a issue I'm also encountering https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq/issues/134